# Store a unique value into database laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

How to store unique `$payment->transaction_id     = Input::get('transact');`
No more `transaction_id` should store with same number

Please suggest me.

```
public function ddclback()
    {

        if(Input::get('statuscode') == 2){
            //Save data into the Database
            $payment                     = new Payment;
            $payment->order_id           = Input::get('orderid');
            $payment->amount             = (Input::get('base_amount', 0))?Input::get('base_amount'):Input::get('amount');
            $payment->amount             = $payment->amount/100;
            $payment->cc_fee             = Input::get('processing_fee', 0);
            $payment->payment_type       = 'CCD-'.Input::get('currency');
            $payment->currency           = Input::get('currency');
            $payment->exchange_rate      = $this->getExchangeRate( Input::get('currency') );
            $payment->gateway            = 'DIBS';
            $payment->payment_date       = date('Y-m-d'); //\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();
            $payment->card_type          = Input::get('paytype');
            $payment->transaction_id     = Input::get('transact');
            $payment->customer_ip        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $payment->save();

            Order::ccid(Input::get('orderid'));
            Order::upord(Input::get('orderid'));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check with where clause before insert record into DB.

Try below code:

```
public function ddclback() {

    if (Input::get('statuscode') == 2) {
        $exist = $this->checkExist(Input::get('orderid'), Input::get('transact')); // check if exist it will return true/ false
        if (!$exist) {

            //Save data into the Database if not exist
            $payment = new Payment;
            $payment->order_id = Input::get('orderid');
            $payment->amount = (Input::get('base_amount', 0)) ? Input::get('base_amount') : Input::get('amount');
            $payment->amount = $payment->amount / 100;
            $payment->cc_fee = Input::get('processing_fee', 0);
            $payment->payment_type = 'CCD-' . Input::get('currency');
            $payment->currency = Input::get('currency');
            $payment->exchange_rate = $this->getExchangeRate(Input::get('currency'));
            $payment->gateway = 'DIBS';
            $payment->payment_date = date('Y-m-d'); //\Carbon\Carbon::today()->toDateString();
            $payment->card_type = Input::get('paytype');
            $payment->transaction_id = Input::get('transact');
            $payment->customer_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $payment->save();

            Order::ccid(Input::get('orderid'));
            Order::upord(Input::get('orderid'));
        }
    }
}  
public function checkExist($orderId, $transactionId) {
    $existRecord = Payment::where('order_id', $orderId)->where('transaction_id', $transactionId)->get()->toArray();
    if ($existRecord) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dhaval what i am guessing it $payment->transaction_id     = Input::get('transact'); is coming through dibs backend it should come unique bt sometimes it is calling 5 times with same transaction id dont know why any idea

Comment: You should check the code from where this function is called from.

Comment: how can check if order_id exists in db and transaction_id exists it will save only one data in the same code

Comment: @Jimmy please check my updated answer i have created one function to check if record exist or not with given orderId and transactionId. if record exist then it will return true otherwise false so you can determined whether to insert record or not.

Comment: Thanks for ton! @Dhaval